# react-router-dom not found in npm registry

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, clone, react-router-v4

I try to clone the react app from the git repo into new machine , but soon after clonning i tried to install npm in order to deal with the dependencies but every time it shows me the error

below is my package.json file

I already tried to update my package.json file with latest version
reinstall the npm and node

Below are the error messages i got when i ran `npm install` command into that project folder

```
Not found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-router-dom/ -/react-router-dom-4.4.0.tgz

ERR!44 'react-router-dom@4.4.0' is no the npm registry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change version for `react-router-dom` in your `package.json` to `5.0.0` instead of `4.4.0`.

> In the end, we decided that the fix that would cause the least pain for everyone would be to npm unpublish version 4.4.0 and re-release it as 5.0.0.

this is quoted from the developers of `react-router-dom`.

Due to some issues they unpublished that version of it.